# Win10 black screen, impossible to boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, windows-update

Someone from my family asked me if I can fix his laptop which can't boot.
Here is the problem :

- When I try to power on the laptop, nothing is shown on the screen (It's black all the way). It does not ventilate for a while and after a minute it ventilate the faster it can.
- I think the lap's battery is a bit strange : After being charged, the battery can't hold the lap on so sometimes it shut down.

what i've tried

- Enter in the BIOS by taping F8 (also tried F2, F3, F5, F12)
- connect the lap to a screen with HDMI / HDMI. nothing is shown on the second screen either.
- Remove the battery and test again

None of these worked. And here is some details :

- I was told that the lap was updating and was stuck at 99%, after that it was manually shut down and this is at this moment it won't power on anymore (It's obviously the cause of the problem).
- The lap is a low cost Toshiba but I don't have the reference.

If someone can advice me to do something, I would be glad to help the owner :)
thanks a lot !